# Remove an element from a vector if it belongs to another vector in R

Tags: r

I have a vector `v1` and `v2`. I want to remove all elements from `v1` which belongs to `v2`. How can I do it in R?

For instance:

```
v1 = 1:10
v2 = 3:5
```

and I want an output as

`1 2 6 7 8 9 10`

Comment: `dplyr::setdiff(v1, v2)`

Comment: You do not need dplyr for setdiff. It is in pkg-`base`

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer by myself, it would be

`v1[!(v1 %in% v2)]`

Answer (score 0):

In base:

```
setdiff(v1, v2)
```

Or use the `Hmisc` package:

```
library(Hmisc)
v1[v1 %nin% v2]
```

Comment: You do not need Hmisc for `%in%`

Comment: It's `%nin%`, not `%in%`. @42-

Comment: Oh. Then it's just `!v1 %in% v2`

Comment: The setdiff approach is incorrect here since it will only report the set (each unique element once) but not the whole remaining vector.